# How to calculate sample variance for "moving" sample using Google Sheets and arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sampling

I have a large set of time-based data and wish to sample the variance for small incremental subsets of the data using a "moving window".

| Time | Data | VAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/14 11:16 | 32.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:22 | 32.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:28 | 32.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:33 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:39 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:44 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:50 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 11:56 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 12:01 | 33.0 |  |
| 03/14 12:07 | 34.0 | 0.40 |
| 03/14 12:13 | 34.0 | 0.49 |
| 03/14 12:18 | 35.0 | 0.76 |
| 03/14 12:24 | 35.0 | 0.87 |
| 03/14 12:35 | 35.0 | 0.82 |
| 03/14 12:41 | 35.0 | 0.89 |

[Data Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11NmfG1zFvmxaIcb-fZTgVYwNrBIFCUsxhTij1tQQLu4/edit?usp=sharing)

I can get the required variance using either row numbers:

VAR(INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(ROW()-9,"0")&":B"&ROW()))   //Variance for the previous 10 rows

or times (there being approximately 10 rows of data per hour)

VAR(QUERY(A:B,"select B where A > datetime '"&TEXT(A11-60/(24*60),"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' and A <= datetime '"&TEXT(A11,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'",0))   //Variance for data accumulated during the past hour

but I have not been able to wrap an ARRAYFORMULA around either of these formulae which, I believe, is the desired solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with BYROW and OFFSET:

```
=BYROW(B11:B,LAMBDA(d,VAR(OFFSET(d,-10,0):d)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Martin.  I had considered BYROW but never thought of combining that with LAMDA (and I will now have to research LAMDA in more depth).

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! BYROW is always used with LAMBDA, it's the way to name the variable you're using in the formula expression later. You can check the [doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) to see some examples 

Comment: Thanks - I now have a better understanding of LAMBDA but what is the purpose of the ":d" and, this is not a showstopper, but would it be possible to have the formula in row 2 and then to either have 0 in the rows preceding row 11 or to have the VAR range just cover the preceding (<10) rows?

Comment: `OFFSET(d,-10,0):d` are actually two cell references, like B1:B11,B2:B12, etc. What LAMBDA names is a cell, and OFFSET returns another cell. Putting them with ":" in the middle is actually a range. Does it make sense?

Comment: Other thing, you may want to change `-10` with `-9` to go from B2:B11 and so on. I've put -10 because of your previous formula, but just for you to check. About the other question: `=BYROW(B11:B,LAMBDA(d,IF(row(d)<11,0,VAR(OFFSET(d,-10,0):d))))` or `=BYROW(B11:B,LAMBDA(d,VAR(OFFSET(d,MAX(ROW(d)*(-1)+1,-10),0):d)))` are two ways of completing the previous rows. The first returns 0 and the second should return the smaller range. Change it to `MAX(ROW(d)*(-1)+2,-9)` if you change -10 with -9

Comment: "Putting them with ":" in the middle is actually a range" - of course!
I actually had tried both the formats you provided before asking and neither works because both just start the original VAR calculation from the "formula" cell.  I.e. no preceding buffer of 0's...

Comment: Oh, have you tried changing B11:B to B2:B?. I've forgotten in my previous comment